# TransactionAttributeType SUPPORTED | NOT SUPPORTED

Tags: transactions, ejb

Recently I stumbled upon code that declared NOT_SUPPORTED as transaction attribute type. I started to wonder what the actual semantics/benefits/implications are.

I found this article on which I commented my thoughts but I am not at all sure that I got it all correctly.

http://www.developerscrappad.com/709/java/java-ee/making-sense-of-ejb3-x-transaction-attributes-part-3-difference-between-supports-and-not_supported/

I also found this article very interesting as it suggests that one of the main differences is the isolation of uncommitted data.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts2/index.html

One point that is still unclear to me regards the costs of suspending and resuming existing transactions (which implicitly happens with NOT_SUPPORTED). I wonder if those costs are neglectable or possibly significant. Anybody can shed some light on that?